# Natural log in indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

If we have indefinite integral and it is in the form $\frac{1}{?}$ where d(?), can we always say that the solution is $ln(?)+C$ and if not in which cases we cannot apply it?

Comment: Almost, it depends on the domain of the function $\dfrac{1}{?}$. That is why absolute values are typically used: $$\int \dfrac{1}{?} d(?) = \ln|?|+C$$

Comment: So suppose we have d(x) and ? is $x.(x-1).sinx.\sqrt{x}$ where x is x>0 can we apply it?

Comment: I suppose you could try, if the answer was $f(x)$ writing it as $\log(e^{f(x)})$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int {f'(x)\over f(x)}\,dx= ln(|f(x)|)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong when considering complex variables.

But the way to check an antiderivative, is to differentiate and see if you get back the integrand.

Comment: And what is the difference between the solution$ \frac{x^a+1}{a+1}$ and $\frac{x^a}{lna}$

Comment: Differentiate them each and see what is the difference.